# How do I use sass globally in my Nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I have a Vue.js component and I would like to access my sass variables from my scss file. On the NUXT documentation https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/ it says that you can use node sass and sass-loader to do this. So I installed both of those and they are under dev dependencies in my package.json.

After that I added the following to my nuxt.config.js

```
  css: [
    '@/assets/sass/main.scss'
  ],
```

But when I try to do this in one of my components

```
<style lang="scss">
html, body{
    background-color: $background-color;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

I get the error that $background color is undefined? Why is this happening?

My main.scss located in assets/sass

```
$text-color:#FFFFFF;
$background-color: #FFFFFF;
$primary-color: #1F2338;
$secondary-color: #F73455;

$navigation-opacity: 0.70;
```

Comment: That just adds the compiled CSS styles of `main.scss` into your markup. You'd rather need to use something like that: https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader

Comment: I'm confused doesn't Nuxt automaticly compile whatever is in the asset folder?

Comment: You name it: It compiles. But it doesn't preserve SCSS for you, especially for other SCSS files. You've to take care of that yourself within your build system. Nuxt just generates plain old CSS, it doesn't allow you to work with variables like the way you try to.